# Java - IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Tags: java

```
public static boolean play123(ArrayList<Card>list){
    boolean win=false;
    int round=1;
    for(int i = 0;i<=list.size();i++){
        Deck.handOutNextCard(list);     
        if(list.get(i)==Card.AceClub ||list.get(i)== Card.AceDiamond ||list.get(i)== Card.AceHeart ||list.get(i)== Card.AceSpade){
            if(round==1){
            System.out.println("You loose! " +list.get(i)+"From round: "+round); 
            i = list.size()+1;
            win = false;
            }
        }
        else if(list.get(i)==Card.TwoClub ||list.get(i)== Card.TwoDiamond ||list.get(i)== Card.TwoHeart ||list.get(i)== Card.TwoSpade){
            if(round==2){
            System.out.println("You loose! " + list.get(i)+"From round: " +round);
            i = list.size()+1;
            win = false;
            }
        }else if(list.get(i)==Card.ThreeClub ||list.get(i)== Card.ThreeDiamond ||list.get(i)== Card.ThreeHeart ||list.get(i)== Card.ThreeSpade){
            if(round==3){
            System.out.println("You loose! " + list.get(i)+"From round: " +round);
            i = list.size()+1;
            win=false;
            }
        }else{
            if(round<3){
                list.remove(0);
                i=0;
                round++;
            }else{
                list.remove(0);
                i=0;
                round=1;
            }
        }
        if(list.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("You win ! ");
            win = true;
        }
    }
    return win;
}
```

I got sometimes IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 error when using the method for example about 100 times, what could be the problem ://
I have tried to fix it through using different loop types but it was not possible, and the index and the size are different sometimes, and this is the handOutNextCard(list) method:
public static Card handOutNextCard(ArrayListlist){

```
    Card current = list.get(0);
    list.remove(0);
    return current;

}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on, according to the stack trace?

Comment: why are you using <= in you for loop on a list size ? You should use < only because it's 0 indexed.

Comment: I want to give you a better, clearer, shorter code. Is `Card` an enumetation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Addressable Indices

`List` is addressable from `0` to `n - 1` (where `n` is the size).

```
for(int i = 0;i<=list.size();i++){
```

should be something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
```

The [`List.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) Javadoc says (for `Throws`)

> [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`

### To Remove while Iterating

Also, the only safe way to remove an item from a `Collection` (while you're iterating it) is with [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29). The Javadoc of which states (in part)

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Comment: Correct, but any good answer should (to me) expand on the following theme : **NEVER modify a list while iterating it**

Comment: I have tried through changing the loop as you said but it still gives me the same error when its called many times :///

Comment: @Llll1 `i = list.size()+1;` is two elements passed the end of the `list`. The last element is at `list.size()-1`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you so much (Y) That was the problem :))))